# Jenkins does not show configured git credentials

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab

I have Jenkins 2.204.2 and want to configure a project with my git credentials for our gitlab server.

I created under `Jenkins > Credentials > System > Global credentials` an entry with a secret key.

Nevertheless, if I create a freestyle project and set `git` as source code management, the opttions for `Credentials` remain empty.

Also if I use the `Add` button next to the credentials options and add the same secret key again, this does not show up in the options (though the new entry is shown in the `Global credentials` menu).

How can I configure the credentials to be used for Jenkins ? What do I miss, that I cannot select my created credentials ?

Answer (score 8):

To use the git protocol (and not the https protocol) your Jenkins credentials must be of type "SSH Username with private key".

Even so, those credentials won't appear in the dropdown list due to this known issue: likely you have installed the "Authorize Project" Plugin and in the "Configure Global Security" > "Project Default Build Authorization" section, "Strategy" field configured to "Run as specified user" (and a user) or "Run as anonymous". As a workaround for the issue, you can select "Run as SYSTEM" and the SSH credentials will appear in the list.

See:

Why credentials are not listed in the GIT SCM section?
https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017499672-Why-credentials-are-not-listed-in-the-GIT-SCM-section-

Comment: I checked and I do not have Authorize Project plugin installed in my Jenkins. Also, when I checked the Strategy field in Configure Global Security, there's no option called Run as SYSTEM. Perhaps because of a newer version of Jenkins?

Comment: @Sandun facing similar issue, how did you fixed?

Comment: Give the credential `GLOBAL` scope instead of the `SYSTEM` scope made the credential visible in `git plug`. I do not have `Authorize Project` plugin

Comment: @FrankLiu this was the same for me.  Switching from System to Global my credentials started to show up!  Thank you!

Comment: This is exactly the issue I am facing. Now I just need to find a way to run certain jobs as 'SYSTEM' while the default stays as is.

Answer (score 0):

When creating it, try changing its `Kind` to `Secret text` (at `<JENKINS_URL>/manage/credentials/store/system/domain/_/newCredentials`) rather than the default `Username and Password`. The contents stay the same (generated on Github's website as `Github Personal Access Token` ([docs](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/managing-your-personal-access-tokens)), but this time no login, just Secret).

This enabled the display of the token in the drop-down menu of the GitHub Plugin (GitHub servers > Credentials at `<JENKINS_URL>/manage/configure`).